# How do I SET DATEFIRST 1 with PetaPoco in a Query or manage pooled connections

Tags: petapoco

I have a query that groups results by week.
In order to ensure a consistent week start I am trying to add the first line into a Peta Poco db.Query(sql) method.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
SELECT
    count(logDate) as Value,
    dateadd(WEEK, datediff(WEEK,0, logDate),0) as [Date]
FROM
    ... etc ...
```

Without the `SET DATEFIRST 1` PetaPoco generates something like...

```
exec sp_executesql N'   
                SELECT      
                    count(logDate) as Value,
                    dateadd(WEEK, datediff(WEEK,0, logDate),0) as [Date]
                FROM
                ... etc ...
```

With the `SET DATEFIRST 1` PetaPoco generates something like...

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [DataPoint].[Date], [DataPoint].[Value] FROM [DataPoint]    
                SET DATEFIRST 1
                SELECT
                    count(logDate) as Value,
                    dateadd(WEEK, datediff(WEEK,0, logDate),0) as [Date]
                FROM
                ... etc ...
```

How do I get around this generating the incorrect SQL?
From the docs it looks like I can use `db.Execute("SET DATEFIRST 1");` as long as it executes on the same connection, but since the connections are all managed for me, do I need to do anything to ensure it's the same connection as my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a semicolon as first char to tell PetaPoco to execute the query as is

```
  db.Execute(";SET DATEFIRST 1 ....
```

Comment: Thanks (gratuitous comment to earn a hat), and I'm thankful :-)

Comment: A note here for anyone else coming here. I'm using the SQL Builder, and tried to do `await db.ExecuteAsync(";SET DATEFIRST 1");` then my query and it wouldn't work correctly. I had to first to an append on the sql builder that was to be used in my query.